# create new table in destination

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have to create a package that creates several new tables daily. this is what i have: 
source comes from SQL server and the data is copied as is in new server, but every day when the package runs it has to create new table with date stamp.

I have variable that creates table name that contains date + name, I use this var in another var that creates table. no errors.

I get error when i create destination and select data access mode = table name or view name variable and select my var that creates table, i get error telling me that the connection string is not valid, because there is no table.

How can i tell SSIS: i am working on it, if you run it, the table will be there.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called 'DelayValidation' in `Data Flow Task`'s Properties. If you set that value to true, SSIS won't check for the table's existence until that Data Flow begins.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called 'DelayValidation' in Data Flow Task's Properties. If you set that value to true, SSIS won't check for the table's existence until that Data Flow begins.

kyooryu, if you chose to undelete your answer, comment on this and I'll delete mine.

Comment: But does it also apply to separate data flow task elements? The author had problem with setting the destination element, I deleted my answer because I thought it does not work on individual elements in Data Flow Task.

Comment: hey guys, I have DelayValication set to True, still getting connection error, even thought don't get it when i created both connections